# div not separating lines with clear or br

Tags: html, css, newline, message

Hey guys got a small issue here and a fix would be much appreciated, thank you for the upcoming support.

I have a form and want to post messages whenever there are issues with the login, such as wrong password, or account hasn't been activated, but when I add the bar it just shoves it next to it, instead of putting the form under the message bar.

[image]

what am I doing wrong? Here is my jsfiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/g1cj39ty/

I am unsure how to post code without indenting 150 lines of code.

```
              <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>2 Column CSS Layout</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin:20px;
        font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color:#555;
    }
    #page {
        background-color:#fff;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:left;
        width:755px;
        padding:0 10px;
    }
    #header {
        border-bottom:0px solid #000;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px
    }
    /* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
    #nav {
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    #nav ul {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:11px;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display:inline-block;
        list-style:none;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        border-top:1px solid #ccc
    }
    #nav li {
        margin:auto;
        display:inline-block
    }
    #nav li a {
        display:block;
        padding:8px 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:700;
        color:#069;
        border-right:1px solid #ccc
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
        color:#c00;
        background-color:#fff
    }

    /* End navigation bar styling. */


    #content {
 padding:30px 0 30px 0;
        width:100%;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    #content p {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #footer {
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        font-size:9pt
    }
    #footer p {
        float: right;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

/* FORM CSS */

    form {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }
label {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

input {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 65%;
}

input[type=submit] {
padding:5px 15px; 
background:#ccc; 
border:0 none;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer; 
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
padding:5px 15px; 
background:#a3a3a3; 
border:0 none;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer; 
}
/* END FORM CSS */



.clean-gray{
border:solid 1px #DEDEDE; 
background:#EFEFEF;
color:#222222;
padding:4px;
text-align:center;
width:500px;
    }


</style>
   </HEAD>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div style="float: left;">
Please Login
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="content">

<div class="clean-gray">Clean message box</div>

<form id="myForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <label for="un">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="username"/>
    <br/ >
    <label for="pw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="password"/>
    <br/ >
<br class="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"> <br>

                        <div style="float: left;">
 <a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password</a> 
            </div>

            <div style="float: right;">
 <a href="register.php">Register</a> 
            </div>
</form> 
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
<div style="float: right;"> copyright 2014 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to look?

Comment: the message bar is supposed to be above it, not next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is being cause the `display: flex;` in #content. That style enables the CSS3 [flexbox layout mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) which is a way to control the arrangement of elements in a container that can change dimensions. To over simply a bit it is basically a way to make columns.

You can either remove that style, or if you need it you can add `flex-direction: column;`(the default is row) to force the form below the bar.

This feature is fairly well supported among modern browsers. According to caniuse.com it will work in IE11, Firefox 31+, Chrome 37+, Safari 7+, and Opera 23+. There more details at the [caniuse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) including some mobile browsers, known issues, and links to more resources.

Comment: Will anything ever work in every browser? :) I updated my answer with some browser support details.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display:flex;`
from your `#content` and go from there.

```
    #content {
 padding:30px 0 30px 0;
        width:100%;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 none;

        align-items:center;
    }
    #content p {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Updated Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cj39ty/1/)

Comment: It seems to mess up my website after I do that, http://i.imgur.com/qy24W10.png What is a way to still set it without the flex option?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by messed up. I don't know exactly how you want it to look, so that is for you to tinker with. If you mean the copyright sneaking up between the hyper links, try adding padding to the top of it or give it a fixed position from the BOTTOM of the page.

Comment: another user helped me out, but I am still upvoting as a useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for something like this is not let me know [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cj39ty/2/)

```
   body {
        margin:20px;
        font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color:#555;
    }
    #page {
        background-color:#fff;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:left;
        width:755px;
        padding:0 10px;
    }
    #header {
        border-bottom:0px solid #000;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px
    }
    /* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
    #nav {
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    #nav ul {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:11px;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display:inline-block;
        list-style:none;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        border-top:1px solid #ccc
    }
    #nav li {
        margin:auto;
        display:inline-block
    }
    #nav li a {
        display:block;
        padding:8px 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:700;
        color:#069;
        border-right:1px solid #ccc
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
        color:#c00;
        background-color:#fff
    }

    /* End navigation bar styling. */


    #content {
 padding:30px 0 30px 0;
        width:100%;
    position:relative;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    #content p {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #footer {
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        font-size:9pt
    }
    #footer p {
        float: right;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

/* FORM CSS */

    form {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }
label {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

input {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 65%;
}

input[type=submit] {
padding:5px 15px; 
background:#ccc; 
border:0 none;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer; 
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
padding:5px 15px; 
background:#a3a3a3; 
border:0 none;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer; 
}
/* END FORM CSS */



.clean-gray{
border:solid 1px #DEDEDE; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:15%;
background:#EFEFEF;
color:#222222;
padding:4px;
text-align:center;
width:500px;
    }
```